# Client POST of indeterminate length to a server

Tags: akka-http

[Java DSL] I'm trying to post a stream of bytes to a server (as the body) using the client api in real-time but won't know the length prior to the start of the request.

I can't figure out how to do this from the akka-http documentation, has anyone attempted this?

Answer (score 0):

Given that, you have created a `materializer` from the Akka context and have a `Source` that generates `ByteString` objects called `mysource`:

```
Http httpContext = 
    Http.get(context().system());

Source<ByteString, NotUsed> chunked = 
    mysource.map(str -> ByteString(str.concat("\n")))
        .concat(Source.single(ByteString.empty()));

HttpRequest post = HttpRequest.POST("http://some-server/address")
    .withEntity(HttpEntities.createChunked(ContentTypes.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, chunked))
    .withProtocol(HttpProtoclas.HTTP_1_1);

CompletionStage<HttpResponse> result =
    httpContext.singleRequest(post, materializer);
```

Note that we concatenate an empty `ByteString` Source object to the original `Source` in order to signal the end of the chunked stream.

If you are issuing this from within an actor it's best to use a `pipe()` to submit the final request.